# Unable to Relate DataTable with another C#

Tags: c#, sql, database, visual-studio-2010

So, I'm aware that you relate DataTables through related columns... Although I have a slight problem.

Example:

Parent Table - **Customers** -> {customerName, customerCode(PK), telphoneCell, ... etc}

Child Table - **Orders** -> { customerCode, orderCode(PK) dateStart, dateEnd, ... etc}

now...

Grandchild Table(s) - **ManufacturingSheet** -> {panelNumber, panelWidth, panelHeight, ... etc}

There are also a few textboxes displaying amounts of parts such as bolts & nuts that I have calculated from user input.

So how can I save this whole Form to an order made by a single Customer? The Customer- name, code, and date details etc also appears on this Form.

Even if I can link a texbox to the **Orders** table, how would I link, that, to the rest of the form?

Here is the Code displaying all the Grids & textboxes I want to be stored in database:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace PalisadeWorld
{
public partial class ManufacturingSheet : Form
{
    public ManufacturingSheet()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    //all the calculated sizes, and parts
    public string[] dis_Width { get; set; }
    public string[] dis_Height { get; set; }
    public string[] dis_Comments { get; set; }
    public int[] dis_PaleQty { get; set; }
    public int[] dis_Blocks { get; set; }
    public int dis_num { get; set; }

    //Method to Convert a string array to int array
    private int[] ConvertArray(string[] s, int rows)
    {
        int[] intArray = new int[rows];

        for (int x = 0; x < rows; x++)
        {
            intArray[x] = Convert.ToInt32(s[x]);
        }
        return intArray;
    }

    //Methods returning other parts calculated with sizes above
    private int GetTotalBearers(string[] bearers, int rows)
    {
        int i;
        int totalBearers = 0;
        int[] temp = ConvertArray(bearers, rows);
        for (i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            if (temp[i] >= 2200)
            {
                totalBearers += 6;
            }
            else totalBearers += 4;
        }
        return totalBearers;
    }
    private int GetTotalPales(int[] pales, int rows)
    {
        int i;
        int totalPales = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            totalPales += pales[i];
        }
        return totalPales;
    }
    private int GetTotalBoltsNutsBrackest(int[] pales, int rows)
    {
        int totalBolts = GetTotalPales(pales, rows) + (rows * 4);
        return totalBolts;
    }

    private void ManufacturingSheet_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //displaying number of respective parts
        numBearers.Text = string.Format("{0}", GetTotalBearers(dis_Height, dis_num));
        numPales.Text = string.Format("{0}", GetTotalPales(dis_PaleQty, dis_num));
        numBrackets.Text = numBearers.Text;
        numBoltsNutsWashers.Text = string.Format("{0}", GetTotalBoltsNutsBrackest(dis_PaleQty, dis_num));

        int i;
        int no = 0;

        //displaying sizes etc in DataGrid
        for(i = 0; i < dis_num; i++)
        {
            // Create a new row.
            PalisadeWorldDatabaseDataSet.ManufacturingSheetRow newOutputRow;

            newOutputRow = palisadeWorldDatabaseDataSet1.ManufacturingSheet.NewManufacturingSheetRow();

            newOutputRow.no = ++no ;
            newOutputRow.cutSize = string.Format("{0}", dis_Width[i]);
            newOutputRow.block = string.Format("{0}", dis_Blocks[i]);
            newOutputRow.height = string.Format("{0}", dis_Height[i]);
            newOutputRow.palesQty = string.Format("{0}", dis_PaleQty[i]);
            newOutputRow.comments = string.Format("{0}", dis_Comments[i]);

            // Add the row to the Region table 
            this.palisadeWorldDatabaseDataSet1.ManufacturingSheet.Rows.Add(newOutputRow);

            // Save the new row to the database 
            this.manufacturingSheetTableAdapter.Update(this.palisadeWorldDatabaseDataSet1.ManufacturingSheet);

            this.manufacturingSheetTableAdapter.Fill(this.palisadeWorldDatabaseDataSet1.ManufacturingSheet);
        }           
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Maybe the **ManufacturingSheet** is more of a Report rather than a Dataset, But it still needs to be saved under the Customer's details

Answer (score 0):

THe DataAdapter allows you to define multiple tables and their relationships, and to define insert and update commands for each table (as well as select commands and delete commands).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.aspx

As for the GUI question, typically you would have OrderItems table (often named OrderDetail) and you would use a DataGrid to capture the one or more items on an order:

```
        OrderItems
        OrderID
        ItemID   typically references a Parts table
        Quantity
        UnitPrice
```

Comment: normally yes. But these panels all are the same product just with different sizes and commonly the same size as well. And there would be no use in using panelNumber as reference, since its only a counter